# No of concurrent users on ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

How many concurrent users ejabberd supports?I read some where 65k.But suppose we listen the request on 5290 port and we know one port can support only 1024 users.So how it will handle 65k users online?

Answer (score 2):

This 1024 figure is not a hard limit.

Your system may have a limit (probably lower than this) set which you can adjust (on Linux, "ulimit", for limiting how many open file descriptors are allowed at once), and the Erlang runtime has an environment limit based on the max number of ports (Erlang port, not network ports) that ERLANG_MAX_PORTS is set to.

Check the [Efficiency Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html#ports) and the [Erlang manpage](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/lang/erlang/doc/man/erlang.html#ERL_MAX_PORTS) for a good place to start. The Efficiency Guide has a lot of details about system limits that are good to know.

Keep in mind that these limits are per *node*, not per *cluster*, which radically changes the picture from the client side.

Answer (score 1):

1024 sounds a lot like a default file descriptor limit. That limits is a default value on Linux but can be changed by changing ulimit.